Handling ECONNREFUSED error using redis-mock library
I'm writing certain unit test cases via sinon in nodejs where I need to deal with few redis operations. I tried to go with redis-mock npm library (redis-mock).
When I do:
const redis = require('redis-mock');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

However, whenever I write my test cases, I end up into an error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
It seems, this module needs a running redis server despite it says its a redis-mock.
Can some one provide pointers how to mock/stub using this redis-mock, so that I can avoid this error.

This should be able create a mock Redis client without needing a running Redis server. Check  if some other part of your code is trying to connect to a real Redis server
